# System call compiled as a module?

Tags: linux

My newly implemented system call is compiled as a module. And after so much of effort there comes out an error "undefined reference to sys_mycall". Guys help me out with this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something is wrong with your makefile. Check your Makefile again. it should be something like:
obj-y := mycall.o

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It seems like i did something like obj-m := mycall.o

Comment: Thanks that did it now there is no  '[M]' when I am compiling the kernel now.

Comment: That means you're no longer compiling it as a module. This may or may not be desirable…

Answer (score 0):

System calls cannot be compiled as modules — all entries in the system call table have to be present when the kernel boots. There is no mechanism to add system calls at runtime.

Unless you are adding an entirely novel feature to the kernel, it should not generally be necessary to add new system calls. It is generally considered more appropriate to implement them in terms of standard UNIX operations on special files or devices (e.g, special `/dev` nodes), or in terms of `ioctl()`.

Comment: you mean i can implement it as a module. I tried but i cannot make  a userspace program to pass values to the module and take return values from the module.

Comment: Again, you cannot implement system calls in modules. Whatever you're doing, you will need to come up with some way of interfacing with it using existing system alls.